# Snowflake Kafka Connect JMX configuration to get Snowflake connector metrics

Tags: apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect, jmx

Could someone please help me with a sample JMX config file to get metrics from Kafka connect cluster that is running snowflake kafka connector. I am able to get most of the kafka connect specific metrics, however, couldnt get a solution to extracts metrics for snowflake.kafka.connector MBeab. I have gone through the snowflake and confluent documentation but couldnt find any solution for this issue.

MBean object name:-
snowflake.kafka.connector:connector=connector_name,pipe=pipe_name,category=category_name,name=metric_name